# Div does not slide back up on click / JS

Tags: javascript, html, slidedown, slideup

I'm having a small problem, i cant seem to solve.

I'm having a problem with the functionality of my animated function. When the div is clicked, it  slides perfectly down, but when i click again on the div, it won't slide back up.

Thats the code i use....

```
$("#menu").click(function () {
    if($(this).offset().bottom == -40) {
        $(this).animate({'bottom': '0px'}, 1000);
    }
    else {
        $(this).animate({'bottom': '-40px'}, 1000);
    } 

});
```

However, it works perfectly fine, when my div is positioned on top,left or right of my page, rather on bottom? Thats something i dont understand... but i must say, i'm rather new to Js.

I've set up a jsFiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/JmLqp/438/

Any suggestions?

Thanks, B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the JS to check for the div's `bottom` value, and animate from that. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMCbn/)

```
$("#menu").click(function () {
    if($(this).css('bottom') == '-40px') {
        $(this).animate({'bottom': '0px'}, 1000);
    }
    else {
        $(this).animate({'bottom': '-40px'}, 1000);
   }     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't getting the right value out of `$(this).offset().bottom`.  You could do this instead:

```
var status = "up"
$("#menu").click(function () {
    if(status == "up") {   
       status = "down"
        $(this).animate({'bottom': '100px'}, 1000);
    }
    else {
        $(this).animate({'bottom': '-30px'}, 1000);
         status = "down"
    } 

});
```

Comment: Thats a great solution too. However it works only once clicking on it. I wanted to make my div to slide up and down every time i click on it. But thanks for the answer and the code. :)